# C# QueryExpression inner enumerator

Tags: c#, query-expressions

I have an array of strings with e-mails, comma separated. Example:

```
string[] array = new [] {
   "test@test.com;test2@test.com",
   "stack@test.com;test@test.com"
}
```

I would like an query expression which would allow me to enumerate throug all three e-mail adresses (test@test.com is an duplicate): "test@test.com, test2@test.com, stack@test.com"

My base attempt is following

```
var enum = array.Select((item) => item.Split(';'));
```

The result is (of course) an enumerator with 2 items each containing an array with 2 items.

I don't know how to name that what I want and so I wasn't able to find an answer via google. If you could give me a hint or something I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely looking for LINQ `SelectMany` method :

```
var enum = array
           .SelectMany(item => item.Split(';'))
           .Distinct()
           .ToArray();
```

This will return a string array with unique emails.

Comment: Also, to skip duplicates, use `Distinct()` method.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, you want to use `SelectMany` to return a single, flattened list:

```
array.SelectMany(item => item.Split(';'))
```

Then you want to use `Distinct` to filter out duplicates

```
.Distinct()
```

And then you will be able to enumerate through them all:

```
var emails = array.SelectMany(item => item.Split(';')).Distinct();

foreach (var email in emails) {
    // do stuff here
}
```